# Why almost all deep web shops use the same CMS, and which is it?

Tags: darknet

I am noticing something strange but I can't find any info by "Inspecting elements". I notice that most of deep web stores are using the same CMS/Framework/Script (whatever it is). I am trying to find which is it. I will post some images, all from different stores for you to see the similarities.

Store #1:
[image: Screenshot of store display]

Store #2:
[image: Screenshot of another store with identically configured display]

Store #3:
[image: Screenshot of another store with only minor display differences]

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything you wish - Tor is just a TCP tunnel like STunnel. As for me I do recommend you to use a fully-featured CMS like Drupal + Drupal Commerce or Drupal+Ubercart or Wordpress+WooCommerce: it's an easy task to prevent data leaks from these CMS'es and you will have all the functionality easily extendable. And your shops are like to have a same (co-)owner, because homebrew CMS'es are do happening nowdays but they're too short in spread area.